# IntelliJ cannot resolve symbol "newFixedThreadPool"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cannot-find-symbol

I'm new to IntelliJ and Java in general. 
I'm trying to learn multithreading and I came across the Executors class.

So I wanted test this, here is a sample of my code.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;


public class LegController {
    private List<Runnable> legs;
    private ExecutorService execute;

    public LegController() {
        legs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            legs.add(LegFactory.getLeg("LEFT"));
        }

        execute = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
    }

    public void start(){

        //TODO
    }
}
```

But I get an error : "Cannot resolve symbol 'newFixedThreadPool'". 
I tried "Invalidate cache and restart" but it didn't help, I tried synchronise and rebuild project, but it didn't work either.

I don't understand where this problem is coming from because the class Executors is imported. Besides, there was autocompletion for the static methods of Executors. 
Maybe there is a problem in the importation, but if so, how could I fix it ?

Comment: I'd guess you want  `execute =  Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);`, i.e. without the `new` keyword, which makes the compiler expect a constructor call (and don't call a constructor).

Comment: also there is no Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(int) method.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Remove the keyword `new` in this line:

```
execute = new Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
```

It should be:

```
execute = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
```

The method `newFixedThreadPool` is a static method of class `Executors`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, in fact I did put the keyword new by reflex and thus didn't noticed it.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the new keyword from this line:

```
execute = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(6);
```

Your syntax actually tries to call the constructor of a static inner class 'newFixedThreadPool' within the Executor class. That static inner class does not exist. Instead, you have to call a static factory method...